# React redux - can't pull data from object in component props by key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component. It recieves `questions` - array of objects via reducer and `getQuestions` action.
There is also `currentQuestionNumber` - an integer, zero by default.
I have `questions` array in my state. I've mapped state to props.
In my `render` method I pull `questions` and `currentQuestionNumber` from props.
Inside `return` of my `render`method I can do `{console.log(questions[currentQuestionNumber])}` - it logs the first object (index 0) in the array as expected. 
A question object looks like this
`{id: 1, text: "question 1", options: Array(4), correct: "1"}`
But for some reason I can't do `{console.log(questions[currentQuestionNumber].text)}`- it returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`.
How can I fix it and why is this happening ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { getQuestions } from "../actions/questionActions";

class Question extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getQuestions();
  }

  render() {
    let { questions, currentQuestionNumber } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(questions[currentQuestionNumber])}
        {console.log(questions[currentQuestionNumber].text)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Question.propTypes = {
  questions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  getQuestions: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  questions: state.questions.questions,
  currentQuestionNumber: state.questions.currentQuestionNumber
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getQuestions }
)(Question);
```

Comment: Are you stepping out of the bounds of the array? Can you post the code that is responsible for rendering an individual `Question`?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because your getQuestions() function is asynchronous and in the first render there is not any `questions[currentQuestionNumber]`. Then its `text` is undefined here. So, why can you console.log `questions[currentQuestionNumber]`?

Probably your questions state is an empty array: `[]`. In the first render if you look carefully it should log `undefined` without any error since there is an empty array. After getting questions your component is being re-rendered and you see the question.

But, this is different for your `.text` case. There is not any question at that time, hence when you want to reach a non-existence question's text, react fires this error.

For this kind of situations you should use conditional rendering.

```
render() {
    let { questions, currentQuestionNumber } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {questions.length && console.log(questions[currentQuestionNumber].text)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```